# Get Proper range of linkAttributed From mutableAttributedString string

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using mutableAttributedString string in textview with attributed link text format. I am getting attributed link for two different attributed link without any space. 
But I i am adding same text with attributed link type and then getting only one range for two link attributed string.

I am Using Below Code:

```
func getlinkRange(attributeString: NSAttributedString) -> [MentionStruct] {
        var arr = [DemoStruct]()
        _ =  attributeString.enumerateAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, in: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributeString.length), options: [], using: { (value, range, stop) in
            if let url = value {
                let occurrence = (attributeString.string as NSString).substring(with:range)
                arr.append(MentionStruct(link: url as! String, text: occurrence, range: range))
            }
        })
        return arr
    }
```

Ex:- @TestingName@TestingName

[image]

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: You may want to look for "@" between the occurence found. It's normal behaviour if you print your NSAttributedString with the issue, you'll see it.

Comment: Not Getting Your Point, I Want to separate  both link attributed text from before @..

Comment: Could you print the NSAttributedString for the case when it's not working and show us the value? It works on the Screen shot but not for `@TestingName@TestingName` right?

Comment: Yes, Its Printing single string ...like below @Testing Name Title@Testing Name Title{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd8dd4afcd0> font-family: \".SFUIText\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt";
    NSLink = "connectmention://B898828B-4512-441C-8FD9-87933471F521--1--ed8a784d-c0ef-4ca2-8a70-c493fb8c3c1d";
}

Comment: For `@TestingName@TestingName` it should print only one (and that's a normal issue, but you want to modify it). But for `@Testing Name Title@Testing Name Title` it shouldn't I guess. So there may be an issue on how add the links attributes.